# Changing background of text in edit control

Tags: c++, api, winapi

Can you change the background of text in area of edit control that would stay static?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the parent of the edit control, handle the [WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787524(VS.85).aspx) message,  the wParam of this message is the HDC that the Edit control is about to draw with,
for most CTLCOLOR messages, if you set text and background colors into this DC, the control will use the colors you set.

You can also return an HBRUSH and the contol will use that for any brush painting that it wil do, but many controls don't use brushes much, so that will have limited effect for some
CTLCOLOR messages.  Your best bet here is to return the DC brush, and set the DC Brush color to match the BkColor of the DC.

```
 LRESULT lRet = 0; // return value for our WindowProc.
 COLORREF crBk = RGB(255,0,0); // use RED for Background.

 ... 

 case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
    HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)lParam; 

    // if multiple edits and only one should be colored, use
    // the control id to tell them apart.
    //
    if (GetDlgCtrlId(hwnd) == IDC_EDIT_RECOLOR)
       {
       SetBkColor(hdc, crBk); // Set to red
       SetDCBrushColor(hdc, crBk);
       lRet = (LRESULT) GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH); // return a DC brush.
       }
    else
       {
       lRet = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
       }
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Actually, even though it is the accepted answer, it will not work for edit control as the OP asked for. For that to work, one would need to replace WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC by WM_CTLCOLOREDIT.

Comment: If the edit control is disabled or read-only, use WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC. For regular edit controls, use WM_CTLCOLOREDIT.

Answer (score 8):

WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC is for static text control.

To be simple, you can do this in your winproc:

```
...
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
{
    HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
    SetTextColor(hdc, yourColor);  // yourColor is a WORD and it's format is 0x00BBGGRR
    return (LRESULT) GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH); // return a DC brush.
}
...
```

If you have more than 1 edit control, you can use the item id and lParam to check which one need to be change.

Comment: "*WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC is for static text control*" - it is ALSO for readonly/disabled edit controls, too.

Answer (score 2):

WM_CTLCOLOREDIT allows you to set text and background color(+brush), if you want more control than that, you have to subclass and paint yourself

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
CBrush bkBrush;
RECT ctrlRect;
COLORREF crBk = RGB(255,0,0); // Red color
bkBrush.CreateSolidBrush(crBk);

CWnd* pDlg = CWnd::GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT);
pDlg->GetClientRect(&ctrlRect);
pDlg->GetWindowDC()->FillRect(&ctrlRec, &bkBrush);
pDlg->GetWindowDC()->SetBkColor(crBk);
```

This should change the background color of the edit control

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to set the required color in control's device context and pass an HBRUSH with same color in WM_CTLCOLOREDIT message. If you want to change both foreground & background colors, use SetTextColor t0 change the text color. But you must pass the background color HBRUSH. But if you want to change the text color only, then you must pass a DC_BRUSH with GetStockObject function.