# Is there a way to change the color of the text in a ChooseFont() dialog in the Win32 API?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am developing a basic text editor program with the Win32 API's file editor example, using Dev-C++ from bloodshed.net.

How can I change the text color when I select it on the `ChooseFont()` dialog? In that dialog, everything works except the color changing option.

Below is my code. Choose font dialog, and in the `switch` case I called that function from the menu format and font:

```
CHOOSEFONT cf = {sizeof(CHOOSEFONT)};
LOGFONT lf;
GetObject(g_hFont, sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf);
cf.Flags = CF_EFFECTS | CF_SCREENFONTS | CF_INITTOLOGFONTSTRUCT;
cf.hwndOwner = g_hwnd;
cf.lpLogFont = &lf;
cf.rgbColors = g_editcolor;
if (!ChooseFont(&cf))
    return;
HFONT hf = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
if (hf)
{
    g_hFont = hf;
    SendMessage(g_hEdit, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)g_hFont, TRUE);
}
g_editcolor = cf.rgbColors;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A font doesn't have a color. A device context has a color assigned which it uses when rendering text using a font.

To set a text color for a standard EDIT control, have the parent window handle the [`WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcoloredit) and [`WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcolorstatic) window messages:

> An edit control **that is not read-only or disabled** sends the WM_CTLCOLOREDIT message to its parent window when the control is about to be drawn. By responding to this message, the parent window can use the specified device context handle **to set the text and background colors** of the edit control.

> A static control, **or an edit control that is read-only or disabled**, sends the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message to its parent window when the control is about to be drawn. By responding to this message, the parent window can use the specified device context handle **to set the text foreground and background colors** of the static control.

Use [`SelectObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectobject) to assign your `HFONT` to the provided `HDC`, and set the `HDC`'s text color using [`SetTextColor()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-settextcolor).

Comment: Can you give me a example of the usage of this please i am newbie :C

Comment: @MannyR see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262628/

Comment: Hello i resolved my problem with the guy who i used his code to get works the ChooseFont() function with the way you said before.